# PHP to Jquery through json ruins array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm trying to perform some PHP code and then pass it's results to another PHP script through jquery.
One of these results is an array, and I'm passing it to a GET so it gets to the other script. (alot of work, but I can't have page reloads even tho I have to use PHP).

The problem occurs when I'm trying to put the PHP variable through JQuery.
What I have to do this for me is:

```
var _leafs = <?php echo json_encode($leafs); ?>;
```

When I run `json_encode` on `$leafs` and then print the result (all using PHP), it gives me a json array that has been successfully validated by JSONLint.

When I use the above code and `alert()` the result it's missing the brackets and quotes.
Even weirder is when I pass it through like so:

```
$.get('set_fields.php?pt=' + _path + '&lf' + _leafs, function(data) {
```

The result is this:

```
" string(4) "
"
```

Which shows up to be a `<br>` in my html reader.

Am I missing something when I'm converting it to json?

Additional code:

```
<?php
// Fetch the XML from the URL
if (!$xml = file_get_contents($_GET['url'])) {
    // The XML file could not be reached
    echo 'Error loading XML. Please check the URL.';
} else {
    // Get the XML file
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXml($xml);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

    $paths = [];
    $leafs = [];
    foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//*|//@*') as $node) {
        $isLeaf = !($xpath->evaluate('count(@*|*) > 0', $node));
        $path = '';
        foreach ($xpath->evaluate('ancestor::*', $node) as $parent) {
            $path .= '/'.$parent->nodeName;
        }
        $path .= '/'.($node instanceOf DOMAttr ? '@' : '').$node->nodeName;
        if ($isLeaf) {
            $leafs[$path] = TRUE;
        } else {
            $paths[$path] = TRUE;
        }
    }

    $paths = array_keys($paths);
    $leafs = array_keys($leafs);

    echo "Choose a path<br><br>
            <form>
                <select id='field_dropdown'>";
                foreach($paths as $value) {
                    echo "<option value='".$value."'>".$value."</option>";
                }
    echo    "   </select>
                <button id='send_path'>Send path</button>
            </form>
            ";

}
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#send_path').click(function() {
    var _path = $("#field_dropdown").val();
    // Get the leafs array and send it as a json string to set_fields.php
    var _leafs = <?php echo json_encode($leafs); ?>;
    $.get('set_fields.php?pt=' + _path + '&lf=' + _leafs, function(data) {
        $('#fields').append(data);
    }).error(function() {
        $('#fields').html('Error calling XML script. Please make sure there is no error in the XML file.');
    });
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

And here the code where I want the json array to end up (and then get turned back into a PHP array).

```
<?php
// Match all the fields to the values
$path = $_GET['pt'];
$leafs = json_decode($_GET['lf']);
$fieldLeafs = [];
$pathLength = strlen($path) + 1;
foreach ($leafs as $leaf) { if (0 === strpos($leaf, $path.'/')) { $fieldLeafs[] = substr($leaf, $pathLength); } }

var_dump($path."<br>");
var_dump($leafs."<br>");
?>
```

Comment: Looks like you're seeing the output of `var_dump()`. Show us the full PHP code (the relevant part).

Comment: @AmalMurali I've added my code.

Comment: remove the `var_dump()`s

Comment: @ekhaled Ok, but now how am I supposed to see the result?

Comment: does the browser console show a json object if you run `console.log(_leafs);` after the variable assignment?

Comment: `ReferenceError: _leafs is not defined`. Guess _leafs is not being set properly, even though alerting it after it's being "set" does show me the ruined json array. Could it be because the file where everything is being set is called by a jquery.get? I tried to do `var _leafs = 'hai';` and console.log that, but it says it's undefined aswell.

Comment: Another test: I tried the same with _path, which also shows up as undefined, yet it does show up when I var_dump(); it at the script that I'm calling.

Comment: I'm kind of lost because it's not clear which php code belongs to what file and who is calling who, but maybe if you change the var_dumps on the last bit of code for `return json_encode(...)` your `$.get` call will be able to read the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you get the array through jquery instead of echoing it?

```
<input id="hidden-value" value="<?php echo json_encode($leafs); ?>" />
```

and then

```
var _leafs = $('#hidden-value').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

What about adding an `=` after the `lf` query parameter when you build the get URI?

```
$.get('set_fields.php?pt=' + _path + '&lf=' + _leafs, ...
```

Comment: Not sure why the `=` was missing, but I've added it now. No changes though.

Answer (score 0):

Just write **'json'** in the last parameter of get method:

```
   $.get('set_fields.php?pt=' + _path + '&lf' + _leafs, function(data) {
        $('#fields').append(data);
    },'json')//<-- this
     .error(function() {
        $('#fields').html('Error calling XML script. Please make sure there is no error in the XML file.');
    });
```

Comment: This causes the custom error "Error calling XML script".

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
var _leafs = [<?php foreach($leafs as $leaf){ echo "'$leaf',"; } ?>]
```

Comment: This gives me exactly the same result.

Comment: Make array like this and parse it to $.get() 
var _leafs =   { 0: true, 1: false };
Or else as your question, you can apply $.ajax() rather using $.get